# No event on left click for button in jQueryMobile app

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, apex-code, visualforce

i am building an mobile application for sfdc.

i am using apex and visual force and jquery mobile js to create my app.

i have used apex:command button and apex:commandlink.

but when i click those buttons the event is not generated , whereas when i right click on the button the button functions as required

```
    <apex:commandLink value="Save"  action="{!HRSave}"/>
    <!--<apex:commandbutton value="Save" style="font-style:italic" action="{!HRSave}"/>-->
```

Comment: Can you please post the generated html from the visual force page that shows the surrounding html markup with jQuery Mobile attributes.  This will help in understanding the problem.  This doesn't answer your question, but I built a jQuery Mobile app on Salesforce, and have post about it here http://brianpfeil.com/2011/09/10/salesforce-and-jquery-mobile.html that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Is commandLink working but commandButton not working?

You might try either passing it via JavaScript to an actionFunction component or look into JavaScript Remoting.  Remoting is excellent with jQuery.